# Correct deployment script for Azure Git backed continuous Deployment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, typescript, azure-web-app-service, kudu

I have a ASP.Net 4.5 MVC application which uses Angular 1.5. The JS code is Typescript and a post build action builds the js code and deploys it to the folder where my application refers to.

I have a Slot on my azure web app which is backed my gitlab repo. Committing to the repo, triggers the deployment, however the post deployment build frequently seems to have issues when a bower/npm or typings library is updated (which is resolved by manually clearing the folder via the kudu console). Does someone have an example of a deploy.cmd script which does the equivalent of

- npm install
- typings install

at the correct point in the pipeline so that the files get deployed correctly.
I want to start scratch with a new slot, and to get the existing slot to work in the past i had to manually install typings for example  `"npm install typings --global"`  in order to get the build to work without a typings error.

**Update Output Below**
I'm guessing that the errors below are due to azure running typescript 1.6 compiler over reference files which need typescript > 1.6.
My csproj has `<TypeScriptToolsVersion>2.0</TypeScriptToolsVersion>`
(ive removed my files from the compile output, but the _all.d.ts file does reference the errored files below

```
  CompileTypeScript:
  D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.6\tsc.exe  --sourcemap --target ES5 --noEmitOnError "REMOVED MY TYPESCRIPTFILES" "D:\home\site\repository\mymvcproject\app\src\_all.d.ts"
D:\home\site\repository\mymvcproject\typings\globals\angular\index.d.ts(1824,32): error TS1110: Build: Type expected. [D:\home\site\repository\mymvcproject\mymvcproject.csproj]
D:\home\site\repository\mymvcproject\typings\globals\angular\index.d.ts(1824,50): error TS1005: Build: ']' expected. [D:\home\site\repository\mymvcproject\mymvcproject.csproj]
D:\home\site\repository\mymvcproject\typings\globals\angular\index.d.ts(1824,58): error TS1005: Build: ',' expected. [D:\home\site\repository\mymvcproject\mymvcproject.csproj]
D:\home\site\repository\mymvcproject\typings\globals\angular\index.d.ts(1824,59): error TS1136: Build: Property assignment expected. [D:\home\site\repository\mymvcproject\mymvcproject.csproj]
D:\home\site\repository\mymvcproject\typings\globals\angular\index.d.ts(1941,1): error TS1128: Build: Declaration or statement expected. [D:\home\site\repository\mymvcproject\mymvcproject.csproj]
Done Building Project "D:\home\site\repository\mymvcproject\mymvcproject.csproj" (Build;pipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder target(s)) -- FAILED.
```

**FINAL UPDATE**
After the typescript team finally generated a version of typescript 2.* which could be installed on Azure, and then the Kudu team deployed it. Now the whole process works! the note from below about using

```
"preinstall": "npm install typescript -g && npm install typings -g"
```

Was the other part of the solution!

Comment: What are the issues when a bower/npm or typings library is updated? Could you please provide the details about the failed deployment? You could log in to Azure Portal, choose your web app, click APP DEPLOYMENT > Deployment options, click on the failed deployment, click the View log link in the Deployment Details blade.

Comment: I've deleted the slot now, and recreated. I ideally wanted a template which work doesnt need me to manually run commands to ensure typings is installed for example. Ill get the messages when i next experience these errors.

Comment: Perhaps, these can get you started?  
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Post-Deployment-Action-Hooks  
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Custom-Deployment-Script

Comment: @Bruce-MSFT after a new slot, same error. I had to manually run npm install typescript -g and npm install typings -g in the console to prevent errors which effectively said unrecognised command "typings"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your requirement, you could follow the steps below to achieve your purpose.

**Create a deployment script**

You could log in to KUDU tool (https://.scm.azurewebsites.net/), click "Tool" > "Download deployment script". Also, you could leverage azure-cli to generate the script. For more details about how to generate deployment script via azure-cli, you could refer to this [tutorial](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-hooks).

**Customize the deployment script**

For using NPM to manage your packages, you could add the following scripts in your package.json file.

```html
"scripts":{
    "preinstall": "npm install typescript -g && npm install typings -g"
 }
```

Then, you need to add the following scripts to the deploy.cmd file.

```html
IF EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\package.json" (
  pushd "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%"
  echo installing npm package
  call :ExecuteCmd npm install --production
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
  popd
)
```

Or you could add the following scripts to install typescript and typings directly via command line.

```html
echo Installing typescript and typings
call npm install typescript -g && npm install typings -g
IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
```

Note: The .deployment, deploy.cmd files need to be placed in the root directory of your solution. You could refer to this [sample](https://github.com/brucechen1019/AspDotNet-MVC-TypeScript) project for details.

Comment: Thanks that's really helpful. The error i am getting incidentally is because Azure web apps don't have Typescript 2 tooling installed currently.  It sounds like this is due some time soon however https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/2156