# Run grunt command in Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'd like to run a `grunt` command to build my html pages after cloning/pulling my code into my App Service webapp.

Doing it manually is one thing (better than nothing), but ideally I could run it automatically. Right now I have a git hook configured to deploy the code to my app service when pushing to a specific branch. This won't update my page unless I can run my grunt command. I can't figure out how to run a script or custom command that would allow me to do this.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my understanding, I assumed that you could leverage [Continuous Deployment to Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-continuous-deployment) and build your custom deployment script for running `grunt` command. Here are some tutorials, you could refer to them:

[Kudu development](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment)

[Kudu development hooks](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-hooks)

[Grunt](https://gruntjs.com/getting-started)

Additionally, here is a similar issue about deployment script, you could refer to [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40017535/correct-deployment-script-for-azure-git-backed-continuous-deployment/40108718#40108718).

Comment: The real key here is to follow the steps at the bottom of the "Kudu development hooks' link. Allow the `deploy.cmd` file to be auto-generated then simply modify as necessary. I chose to add a new step in `deploy.cmd` which was effectively `npm run deploy`, then over in `package.json` I added `"scripts": {"deploy": "grunt ship"}`